# Custom Validator to regular function conversion in Angular8

Tags: angular

So here is an Angular Custom Validator that i have.
The issue is it will never returns null. So i understood that this "function" can't be a validator.
Here is the Angular HTML:

```
      <form [formGroup]="setpw">
    <p>
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
        <input matInput formControlName="password" class="form-control" />
      <p class="pw-strength">Password Strength: {{ setpw.get('password').errors['passwordStrength'] }} 
      </p>
     </form>
```

(Removed unnecessary code)

Here is the validator:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export function PasswordStrengthValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null => {
    let value: string = control.value || '';

    if (!value) {
      return null;
    }

    let upperCaseCharacters = /[A-Z]+/g;
    let lowerCaseCharacters = /[a-z]+/g;
    let numberCharacters = /[0-9]+/g;
    let specialCharacters = /[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+/;
    let s = 0;
    if (upperCaseCharacters.test(value) == true) {
      s++;
    }
    if (lowerCaseCharacters.test(value) == true) {
      s++;
    }
    if (numberCharacters.test(value) == true) {
      s++;
    }
    if (specialCharacters.test(value) == true) {
      s++;
    }

    if (s === 0) {
      return { passwordStrength: '' };
    }

    if (s === 1) {
      return { passwordStrength: 'Weak' };
    }

    if (s === 2) {
      return { passwordStrength: 'Medium' };
    }
    if (s === 3) {
      return { passwordStrength: 'Strong' };
    }
    if (s > 3) {
      return { passwordStrength: 'Very Strong' };
    }
  };
}
```

It's a basic validator as you can see, Working fine.
I want to convert this validator to a function, I've tried few methods with no luck .
The function needs to get the input from the Form Control inside the form Group and do the same as the validator does.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to wrap validator function unless you are passing parameters to parent function. You can define it directly like this :

```
export function PasswordStrengthValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } | null {
   ....
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the valueChange Observable to get the updated value from the input element and can write the validation logic inside the callback.

```
this.setpw.get('password').valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```